# Sqlite query in Android to get the last inserted row by other id

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in Android

I have a table  so.

```
idrow---message---date------transmitter----id_name
 1    |  Hello  | 13-09-14 |   Mike      |    307
 2    |  Thanks | 17-09-14 |   Louis     |     12
 3    |  Byebye | 18-09-14 |   Charlie   |    879
 4    |  Hello  | 18-09-14 |   Mike      |    307
 5    |  bllaaa | 18-09-14 |   Mike      |    307
 6    |  Nice   | 19-09-14 |   Charlie   |    879
 7    |  Great  | 19-09-14 |   Mike      |    307
```

I want to get the last inserted row for each id_name .

For example:

Of id_name 307:     7    |  Great  | 19-09-14 |   Mike      |

Of id_name 879      6    |  Nice   | 19-09-14 |   Charlie   |

Of Louis   12       2    |  Thanks | 17-09-14 |   Louis     |

I try to use this but does not work as expected

```
 String Query = "Select * from TableName, max(id_row) group by id_name" ;
```

Comment: so you want data in reverse order?

Comment: No, I lwant for example having the last message of Patrick, the last of Mike .. etc etc .. Suppose is a screen (activity) where I teach a list of users and only his last message (like whatsapp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query works only in SQLite 3.7.11 or later, which you will not have before API level 16 (Jelly Bean).

In earlier versions, non-grouped columns are not guaranteed to come from the row that matches the MAX().
You have to look up the maximum ID for each `id_name` separately, either with a join:

```
SELECT TableName.*
FROM TableName
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id_row) AS id_row
      FROM TableName
      GROUP BY id_name
     ) USING (id_row)
```

or with IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE id_row IN (SELECT MAX(id_row)
                 FROM TableName
                 GROUP BY id_name)
```

(Both queries work the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Well,you can use the following code too...

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY idrow DESC LIMIT 1
```

and may be you are getting error because of using id_row instead of idrow

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I dont want the last row. I want the last row of each id_name.I lwant for example having the last message of Patrick, the last of Mike .. etc etc .. Suppose is a screen (activity) where I teach a list of users and only his last message (like whatsapp).

Comment: You can try this : ` SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY idrow DESC GROUP BY id_name`

Comment: @chitraketuPandey ORDER BY must come after GROUP BY, and does not affect the grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
select * from TableName
where id_row = (SELECT max(id_row) FROM TableName)
order by id_row desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This returns only the last row, not one row for each `id_name`.